# How can i show a validationMessage (for an input element) programmatically without a Form?

Tags: javascript, html, validationmessage

Im not sure if this is possible *without* using a **form**.
But I would like the browser to render the validation errors.
Again, I am doing this programmatically without a form.

i.e. No Form tag, and no submitting. Just straight-up scripting.

**Updated**

I would like to validate input fields, such as:

```
 <input value="123" maxlength="5"/>
 <input value="hllo wrld" spellcheck="true"/>
```

Comment: might need some more information on this one, what do you want to validate?

Answer (score 0):

If you wan't to validate that fields on page load without any additional submit/click event this can be possible solution :

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

 $("#fieldDiv input").each(function() {

            if(!isNaN(this.value)) {
                alert(this.value + " is a valid number");
            }

        });
```

});

Idea is to traverse all input fields and perfom validation. You can use custom attributes to know what validation to use.

Comment: Yes i could. but i want the browser to show the validation errors.

Comment: Yes, in that "if"...show popup, write message in some div element or anything you need. In my example alert wil show validation info...